# how to convert sqlite to json in android

Tags: android, json

**How to Convert this**

```
 [{destLocId=10, createdUserId=b9ab2d71-9a69-4ba3-b498-d36446a154d6, 

 createdDate=2016-6-29 14:35:00}]
```

**to this :**

```
 [{"destLocId":10, "createdUserId":b9ab2d71-9a69-4ba3-b498-d36446a154d6, 
 "createdDate":2016-6-29 14:35:00}]
```

Comment: Is this just about wrapping names in quotation marks?

Comment: `[{"destLocId":10, "createdUserId":b9ab2d71-9a69-4ba3-b498-d36446a154d6, "createdDate":2016-6-29 14:35:00}]` is not a valid json ... but back on topic ... iterate cursor and build json from it ... should be easy ... what had you tried so far?(other than DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor)

Comment: @JF Meier i want to convert sqlite to json ,first one i m getting  when i m fetching from sqlite table ,now i need that to send to server through json.

Comment: @Mayuri Is the result an ArrayList?

Comment: @ K Neeraj Lal   yes i need that arraylist to be converted to json .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list) library for converting ArrayList to JSON. Here an example,

```
ArrayList<String> bibo = new ArrayList<String>();
bibo.add("obj1");
bibo.add("obj2");
bibo.add("obj3");
String json = new Gson().toJson(bibo);
```

And [this](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples) example from Gson User Guide to use it on collection.